# Canvas, createPattern bug in chrome 18

Tags: html, google-chrome, canvas

I am using mac and updated chrome to 18.0.1025.142.
Now I have a strange problem. In most cases (not always what is weird) method context.createPattern() doesn't work and instead of bitmap filling it's filling with black color.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is an issues: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=113592

I am still looking for a temporary solution on my projects too.

Answer (score 0):

It is a common problem in google chrome and opera , In this case you should create a function that will contain all  script of canvas and also create an  image pattern in this function . Then you need to call  the function at window.onload event or any event , then I think image creatPattern() work well . Just follow the example and try to understand ....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Image to use:</p>
<img src="img_lamp.jpg" id="lamp" width="32" height="32">
<p>Canvas:</p>



<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid   #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>

window.onload = draw;

function draw() {
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height); 
var img = document.getElementById("lamp")
var pat = ctx.createPattern(img, "repeat");
ctx.rect(0, 0, 150, 100);
ctx.fillStyle = pat;
ctx.fill();
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

use your own jpg or png here ... Enjoy !.